# Why .net Framework modify an expression for value types calling a Convert function?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression, value-type

I'm looking for an explanation rather than a solution: here what I noticed.
Let say I have a method Test as below that is working with Expression. Because of the returning `parameter` of the `Func` being `"object"`, when I call the function with a value type property `(Test<TestClass>(x => x.SomeInt))`, the framework wraps my expression into `x=> Convert(x.SomeInt)` and `.Body` not being if type `MemberExpression` anymore. Could it be due to `boxing/unboxing`? but where is this documented.

```
    static void Test<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> memberExpression)
    {
        //if value type, body is Convert(x.SomeInt)
        var body = memberExpression.Body.ToString();
    }

    class TestClass
    {
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Test<TestClass>(x => x.SomeInt);
        Test<TestClass>(x => x.SomeString);
    }
```

Comment: Also where is the body of that Convert function defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because type of lambda is `T => object`. When you cast value types to object .NET runtime needs to do some work (create boxed instance of value type), since Convert. It should not appear when you convert to reference type since casting RefType => object is no op.

You may improve your code by using `Foo<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T,TResult>> expr)`.

Since expressions can be compiled at runtime and generate CIL (.NET bytecode) from it's structure they introduced special node just to generate CIL boxing instruction `box` or to call method to perform custom conversion when user defined conversion exists. This way expression mirrors actual code that would be generated by compiler.